# Consume REST Service with Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, rest

Below is code I use to get data from a SharePoint List with Javascript. What would I need to do to get it work on a site like JS Bin or JS Fiddle with an open/free REST service? (Like iextrading.com?)

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function getCompanies () {

var call = $.ajax({
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Bills')/items?$select=AccountNumber&$orderby=AccountNumber&$filter=(PackageID eq '" + pid + "')",
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
headers: {
Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
}
});
call.success(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
    $("#ResultsDiv").empty();  
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++)   
        {  
            var item = data.d.results[i];  
            $("#ResultsDiv").append(item.AccountNumber + "<br/>");  
        }  
});
call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
alert("Error retrieving Account Numbers: " + jqXHR.responseText);

});


}

</script>

<button onclick="getCompanies(); return false;" type="button">Get Item</button>

<hr width="50px" />
<div id="ResultsDiv"></div>
```

I looked at several examples on SO, but I couldn't get them to work on JS Bin or JS Fiddle.

Comment: Have you looked at the iextrading docs (https://iextrading.com/developer/docs/)? Every API is different. Also the above code won't work in JS Bin or JS Fiddle without references to jQuery (for $) and SP (for _spPageContextInfo) libraries

Comment: $.ajax() is a jquery method. For vanilla JS you need to use XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: I did look at the iextrading docs, but the html example they had was a bit confusing. Note: I don't need this to work with SharePoint, I was simply using that code as an example of my goal (which is read data from a REST api with javascript.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I worded my question poorly, because my original code was close to the answer.

```
function getMovies () {

var call = $.ajax({
url: "https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=[yourKeyHere]",
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
headers: {
    Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
  }
});
call.success(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
    $("#ResultsDiv").empty();  
    $("#ResultsDiv").append(data.Title);  
});
call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
alert("Error retrieving data: " + jqXHR.responseText);

});


}
```